# How to solve the NameError error in a python script ( on linux CentOS)

Tags: python, linux, scripting, centos, nameerror

I am trying to make a Python script on Cent OS 8 but I constantly get this 'NameError' message and I just  can't figure out what could be the problem. Here you'll see screenshots of both my script and the error message.

[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QO1VI.png)

[My script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMKyn.png)

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please include any code inline in your question and not as images. Images are hard to read for many people, not properly searchable and assumes that your current code is legible in image format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to mention the full path of the file "sshdlog" like `with open("full path to sshdlog file") as f` or your script and sshdlog is in same directory.